# Toolbar icon height issue with Firefox on linux

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

Am using the following code to attach a panel to a toolbar button.

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
<toolbarbutton id="test-toolbar-button" 
label="test" 
class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional" 
tooltiptext="test" 
type="panel"
>
<panel class="test-panel" id="test-panel" position="after_end" onpopupshown=""     width="643px" >
<iframe id="test-panel-iframe" src ="chrome://url.html" 
style="height:568px;width:343px;border:none;padding-left:3px;background-color:white;" >
</iframe>
</panel>
</toolbarbutton>
```

As per the documentation we need to specify two icons for Firefox toolbar button - 16x16 and 24x24

This is the CSS am using,

```
#test-toolbar-button {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://test-24.png");
  -moz-image-region: rect(0px 24px 24px 0px);
}

#test-button:hover {
}

#test-toolbar-button[disabled="true"] {
   -moz-image-region: rect(0px 48px 24px 24px);
}

toolbar[iconsize="small"] #test-toolbar-button 
{
    list-style-image: url("chrome://test-16.png");
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 16px 16px 0px);
}
```

But the toolbar height increases since its having a down arrow which indicates its a panel attached to the toolbar button, there by screwing the whole toolbar.

Screenshot of the sample is attached.

http://postimage.org/image/sqwtwbfip/

Can anyone help me out of this.

Comment: What about the CSS styles you are applying to this button? These are definitely not the default styles in your screenshot...

Comment: @WladimirPalant I have added the CSS in my question.

Comment: Weird. Don't know why the theme doesn't take care of it but I guess that you will have to add `-moz-box-orient: horizontal !important;` style to this button yourself.

Comment: @WladimirPalant What does this actually do?

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-orient), it's basically the same thing as `orient="horizontal"` XUL attribute. The default theme already defines that for `type="menu-button"` so that the actual button and the dropdown arrow are laid out horizontally. I don't see any such rule for `type="panel"` however, in your screenshot they are clearly laid out vertically.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Its again screwed in FF 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-moz-box-orient: horizontal !important;
```

This worked . Thanks @WladimirPalant

Comment: I've got exactly this problem with Modify Headers addon and now it's fixed! Thanks @WladimirPalant for the fix and thanks Jeevan for asking the question.

Comment: A bug has already been reported and like you, it only happens on Linux: https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25195